# POI 4.1.0 Line-Chart y-series showed wrong legend

Tags: java, apache-poi

how can i create a line chart with single legend on y-series instead of showing multiple legend bease on x-series

```
int rows = numberOfRows - 1;
int cols = headers.size();

XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15);
XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
chart.displayBlanksAs(DisplayBlanks.GAP);

XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

// Use a category axis for the bottom axis.
XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
bottomAxis.setOrientation(AxisOrientation.MAX_MIN);
bottomAxis.setTitle("Date");

XDDFValueAxis rightAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.RIGHT);
rightAxis.setTitle("Rates");
rightAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

XDDFChartLegend chartLegend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
chartLegend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);
chartLegend.setOverlay(false);

XDDFLineChartData lineChartData = (XDDFLineChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, rightAxis);

XDDFDataSource<String> xs = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, rows, 0, 0));

for (int col = 1; col < cols; col++) {
    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, rows, col, col));
    XDDFLineChartData.Series series1 = (XDDFLineChartData.Series) lineChartData.addSeries(xs, ys1);
    series1.setTitle(headers.get(col), null);
    series1.setSmooth(false);
    series1.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.NONE);
}

chart.plot(lineChartData);
```

[image]

Above image is showing my current plot Line-Chart, the y-series is expect only 1 legend but it was showed multiple

[image]

Above image Line-Chart is plot using excel, the y-series is only show 1 legend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a setting for varying the colors of same-series data markers in a chart. See: [Vary the colors of same-series data markers in a chart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vary-the-colors-of-same-series-data-markers-in-a-chart-395f0c1c-ea89-4fd9-9c5e-fed830e45851?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). That was `false` per default up to `Excel 2007`. Now `Microsoft`decided to make that setting `true` per default. So you need explictly set that `false` if you do not want it.

In your case:

```
...
XDDFLineChartData lineChartData = (XDDFLineChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, rightAxis);
lineChartData.setVaryColors(false);
...
```

Comment: Appreciate so much!!!!!! Your answer help me fixed the y-series! .. tqvm!!!